# need to use single, double quote and variables in selenium find by xpath (python)

Tags: python-3.x, variables, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, quotes

I want to get web data by using selenium find by Xpath function. I need extract multiple information as following:

```
info1=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="res-results-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a')
info2=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="res-results-table"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a')
info3=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="res-results-table"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/a')
```

I want to use variables, but seems something is wrong. what I did was:

```
info=[]
for i in range (1,4)
    info[i] = browser.find_element_by_xpath('\'//*[@id="res-results-table"]/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[1]/a\'')
```

Can anybody help? thank you!

Comment: You don't need the `\'` part.  Just `by_xpath('//*[@id="res-results-table"]/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[1]/a')`

Comment: @Gameisongoing , IMHO it's better not to use this kind of string concatenation. There are more Pythonic ways to do the same, e.g. `'//*[@id="res-results-table"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[1]/a' % i` or `'//*[@id="res-results-table"]/tbody/tr[{}]/td[1]/a'.format(i)`

Comment: Thank you! I am a beginner, will google and try to understand your solution, it looks beautiful and Pythonic !